# beautifulsoup, html5lib: module object has no attribute _base

Tags: beautifulsoup, html5lib

When I updated my packages I have this new error:

```
class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

I tried to update `beautifulsoup`, with no more result. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**edit** nov, 2017: it seems this doesn't work any more

Finally found out, a search engine didn't throw anything but it's referenced on beautifulsoup's issue tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1603299

it works back with html5lib v`0.9999999` (7 nines)

```
"html5lib<=0.9999999"
```

Comment: This fixes a similar bug in kaggle-cli too

Comment: (on W7).Unfortunately i tried both downgrading and upgrading.I also tried to seta virtual env using Python 2.7. Nothing worked so far, basically I am stuck on using beautifulsoup library

Comment: I just overcome this error simply checking that Pycharm was using the wrong interpreter in my virtual env. Indeed in the python idle and Powershell I did not faced such error

Comment: `html5lib<=0.9999999` has a security vulnerability and should not be used any longer. Source: https://www.sourceclear.com/registry/security/cross-site-scripting-xss-/python/sid-3068

Comment: This is the command to fix it: sudo pip install html5lib==0.9999999

Answer (score 116):

I upgraded beautifulsoup4 and html5lib and it resolved the issue.

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
pip install --upgrade html5lib
```

Comment: Confirmed that this worked to get the `sudo pip install spry` to work properly without errors February 2017.

Comment: I required `--force`

Answer (score 27):

This is an issue with upstream package html5lib: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1603299
To fix, force downgrade to an older version:

pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8

Answer (score 8):

The downgrade to html5lib 1.0b8 in @Bhavuk answer works but courses a version issue with bleach.

The solution for me was with a change of version of bleach to be compatible with the new version of html5lib

```
pip install --upgrade bs4
pip install --upgrade bleach==1.4.2
pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8
```

Python version 3.5

Comment: For anaconda, I did `conda install html5lib==0.9999999`, which downgraded bleach to 1.5.0 but it worked

Answer (score 3):

The same problem occurred on me. I don't know what you were trying to do, but it occurred on me when I tried to read XML file in pandas, using `pd.read_html()`.

The problem is fixed by upgrading all of beautifulsoup4, html5lib, and lxml, like:

```
pip install bs4
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

And restart your Python environment and now it is working.

Comment: I needed to add `-U` to upgrade existing installations in some cases, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This command solved the problem for me:

```
 sudo pip install html5lib==0.9999999
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install `html5lib` using this because if you install the normal way then you have to spider using python2.

```
sudo pip3 install html5lib==0.9999999
```

Answer (score 0):

I found trying to switch versions did not work for me. In the end, based [on this issue](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/issues/316#issuecomment-331662556) I edited the relevant file at `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py` for my purposes.