# Spyder3 crash, after install jupyter-notebook

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, spyder

In the notebook machine I was using Spyder3 without any problem until install jupyter-notebook.

When run spyder3 from command line, the next message appear:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in 
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'

after some search try the proposed solutions on:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4309

https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1603299

[beautifulsoup, html5lib: module object has no attribute _base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447738/beautifulsoup-html5lib-module-object-has-no-attribute-base#38799613)

try:

sudo pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4

sudo pip install --upgrade html5lib

sudo pip install spry

Also reinstall:

sudo pip install --upgrade spyder

One year ago in the desktop machine i had the same problem, 
i fixed changing some python code but now dont remember how was fixed it.

Also downgrade the html5lib version to the same version of my desktop computer:

sudo -H pip install html5lib==0.9999999

and beautifulsoup4

sudo -H pip install beautifulsoup4==4.4.1

---

python

> > > import html5lib
> > >
> > > html5lib.**version**

u'0.9999999'

> > > import bs4
> > >
> > > bs4.**version**

'4.4.1'

---

But nothing happen.

The notebook machine have installed:

Ubuntu 16.04 - 32 bit
python 2.7, 3 and 3.5

Any help will be welcome

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm sorry to say it, but due to problems like the one you're describing here is that we recommend using Anaconda instead of pip. Besides, you should really, *really* avoid installing packages with `sudo pip` because you're mixing packages provided by your distribution with the ones installed from PyPI. Instead, you should a virtualenv for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/issues/316

open the file: sudo mousepad /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py

and change :

class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):

with

class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders.base.TreeBuilder):

and

class Element(html5lib.treebuilders._base.Node):

with

class Element(html5lib.treebuilders.base.Node):

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after the installation of spyder3 using the ubuntu package manager: spyder was crashing with 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
Could fix it with:
pip install --user --upgrade spyder
I guess, the '--user' option is the solution to write the right paths of the modules.

Comment: Thanks, i try but still get the same error: AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'